# Why am I unable to serialize my query via DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to pass in some extra key value pairs and running into an error.

```
class execution_details(APIView):
    def get(self):
        this_job_execution = JExecutionSerializer(this_job_execution)

        payload = [{
        'binaries': binaries,
        'stage_logs': stage_logs,
        'job_logs': job_logs,
        'external_link': ext_links,}]
        return Response(this_job_execution.data + payload)
```

error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ReturnDict' and 'list'
```

I'm wondering if there is an issue because this_job_execution is a single record rather than a queryset with multiple records.  I know I have done this in the past with a queryset, so that's why I suspect this is an issue.

Comment: also tried just turning payload into a dict, but got same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding list and dictionary together. If you want to update dictionary, use `dict.update()` function. And make both the result in dictionary.

try this

```
class execution_details(APIView):
    def get(self):
        this_job_execution = JExecutionSerializer(this_job_execution)
        payload = {
        'binaries': binaries,
        'stage_logs': stage_logs,
        'job_logs': job_logs,
        'external_link': ext_links,}

        data = this_job_execution.data
        data.update(payload)
        return Response(data)
```

if x={"a":1, "b":2}, y={"c":3,"d":4} then x.update(y) makes x={"a":1, "b":2, "c":3,"d":4}

if you want to add payload as list inside the response use the following

```
class execution_details(APIView):
    def get(self):
        this_job_execution = JExecutionSerializer(this_job_execution)
        payload = [{
        'binaries': binaries,
        'stage_logs': stage_logs,
        'job_logs': job_logs,
        'external_link': ext_links,}]

        data = this_job_execution.data
        data["payload"] = payload
        return Response(data)
```